# Why does my app in Google Play Store urges to update even though the latest version is already present in device?

Tags: android

I have problem in my Google Play Store. My updated app has update flag in Play Store even though it is already up to date.

Is there anything wrong I did while updating in play store?

Comment: You mean it shows the "Update" button even though you've already updated? I saw this bug yesterday, for the first time, as well.

Comment: Yes. It does. I dont know, what mistake I did. May be release name ? Or Anything? Dont know!

Comment: I think it's just a bug. There are indications that the app isn't actually updating correctly when you press "Update" -- that you're still left with the old version. You might try pushing a new version of the app to google play -- that seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App on Google Play always shows "Update" instead of open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571956/app-on-google-play-always-shows-update-instead-of-open)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the remove the google play store from the stack/recent apps. And then try to load the play store again.
It is just a bug that play store doesn't refreshes the pages that are already loaded.