# Playstore app showing update instead of open, and google sign in not working

Tags: android

I have uploaded an apk in playstore yesterday, version name is 1.0, version code is 1, its uploaded successfully but again showing update instead of open, even it is intalled showing 0 installations in console, along with google sign in not working in playstore, it worked perfectly in signed apk before moving to playstore, please help me

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553534/why-does-my-app-in-google-play-store-urges-to-update-even-though-the-latest-vers#comment94008005_53553534), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568569/play-store-keeps-on-showing-update-option), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571956/app-on-google-play-always-shows-update-instead-of-open#comment94009021_53571956).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App on Google Play always shows "Update" instead of open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571956/app-on-google-play-always-shows-update-instead-of-open)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation on [creating a release on Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en).

Make sure you follow the steps.

Also, it takes about 2 - 4 hours for an app to appear in the Google Play store.

Comment: Hi, its showing in playstore, only problem is showing update button instead of open