# Play store keeps on showing update option

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

I created a new release from Google Play Console for a react native application. Before release I updated the app version code and version name in AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle.

Build commands used are
`gradlew clean` and `gradlew assembleRelease --console plain`

After the app was listed in the Play Store with the new version name, I updated the app and all the changes made in the app was reflected in the app. But even after updating the app, Play Store keeps on showing the "update" button.

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling the app

Comment: Tried. But still having the same issue in all the devices.

Comment: how did you checked your current version with playstore version can you please share your code

Comment: I checked the version name from the description in play store. And which part of the code should I share?

Comment: I checked the version name from the description in play store. this part of code please

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553534/why-does-my-app-in-google-play-store-urges-to-update-even-though-the-latest-vers#comment94008005_53553534) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571956/app-on-google-play-always-shows-update-instead-of-open#comment94009021_53571956).