# App on Google Play always shows "Update" instead of open

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on Google Play that, after an update, always shows the update button. Even if it's already updated and the latest version is shown in app settings, Google Play keeps asking me to update it. What can the problem be? This only happens with this single application. I tried to delete all caches and data (both for play store and the app), but with no results.

Comment: Did you try updating the app again from the playstore?

Comment: Version name may be same, but version code may be different.

Comment: Yes, I click update, it finishes and at the end of the process - update button again.

Comment: I also wanted to add that this happens with everyone that installs this app (which is developed by me). If it's allowed, I can link here the google play link and source code on github.

Comment: I think it's allowed. You can provide link.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553534/why-does-my-app-in-google-play-store-urges-to-update-even-though-the-latest-vers#comment94008005_53553534) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6759241/greeble31?tab=activity). It appears this is a new bug which is popping up.

Comment: So it looks like I'm not the only one. I tried to update multiple times though, but to no avail.

Comment: @Marc are you using split apks? we have the same issue, and just started using them.

Comment: @MarkAronSzulyovszky I am not using split APKs. I have one small less than 1MiB APK, and I experience the same issue. No native APIs used, signed with the same key as usual.

Comment: i have the same issue ,have you solve it ?

Comment: My google ad mob ad are not showing , :(

Comment: We're seeing the same for some of our users. It appears to install the apk but with a version code lower than the actual code, which is causing issues with version support popups for us. We're attempting to send another update now to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I think we're still on hit and miss. The framework I use rewrites the gradle always with the latest versioncode. Unfortunately I continue with the problem, even after sending two updates checking these suggestions (including adrianillo).

Comment: Update: Sending a new app update didn't fix, it actually resulted in a few of our own team members having the same issue. One of our developers says clearing google play cache/storage fixed it, but it's obviously not a fix for our users

Comment: I had the same problem, I have contacted Google Play support they said it is on going bug they will resolve as soon as possible.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.
It was working fine till Saturday i.e 1st Dec 2018 but after updating my app in the evening this issue started. I waited for more than 24 hours but the issue still persists.
I crossed checked my version code and everything but the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: A few hours ago, in my case, the App did not request more updates. It must have been some action from Google, because I did not make any changes. There is no update button, operating normally.

Answer (score 13):

I've contacted Google Play support:

[image]

**UPDATE 2 :**
[image]

**UPDATE 1 :**

Problem solved guys,Google play finally fix their problem by sending an update of (Google Play Libraries), so you don't need to do anything. if you still seeing the UPDATE button,just clear the cache of Google Play from setting.

Comment: please update on that, I have the same issue

Comment: I have also contacted support and I recently received the same reply.

Comment: Even we are facing the same issue... Please update us as soon as you hear anything from the Google play support team...

Comment: @Avi of course i will do.

Comment: Issue appears to be resolved for us too.

Answer (score 6):

We had the same problem, we think it was a bug of the Play Store, because there were more people reporting the same behavior.

To fix it, we simply re-upload the app with a higher versionCode.

Comment: This does not work for me. I uploaded a new application version since the first report and I still see this update button after updating.

Comment: There are indications that the app isn't actually updating correctly when you press "Update" -- that you're still left with the old version. You might try pushing a new version of the app to google play -- that seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: Did not help me either.

Comment: @pcortez for me the application is updated to latest version but the button still remains.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **temporary fix** which is **publishing a new update** (as usual with a higher version code), but it's kind of a hit or miss, if it worked for you then **don't** upload another update until google fixes this issue because if you do then the same problem might recur (probably, because it happened to me twice in the past two days)

Comment: Same thing here

Answer (score 1):

upload a new version with different incremented versionCode

```
versionCode 20181202
versionName '2.0.0'
```

and the most important

```
wait for 1/2 to 1 hour for Google Play to update the app.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I'll tell you how I solved it. It doesn't make much sense what I did, but I'll tell you in case it can help you.

In my build.gradle file I have several configurations to generate my application and each of them has a different versionCode. What I did was to set the same value in all configurations with the latest versionCode value.

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx"
    ..
    versionCode NN
    versionName "x.y"


}

productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        ....
        versionCode NN
        versionName "x.y"


    }
    pro {
        applicationId "xxxx"
       ....
        versionCode NN
        versionName "x.y"          
    }
}
```

It doesn't make much sense because I generate my app with one configuration and the other configurations don't matter. Maybe there's an error and it  takes into account the default configuration. Maybe it was a coincidence and when uploading another new version it was fixed. I also wrote to google support and they may have fixed it but they haven't responded yet.

I know it doesn't make much sense but I'll tell you what I did in case it can help you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I just want to note for other readers that this problem occurs even for applications with no flavors and no version code overrides. Mine is a single flavor with hardcoded version code and has this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly the same issue. I contacted Google Developer support thrice. Today I got a reply, this is the latest email I received from them. 
PS: I released my update(new version) from Android Studio v3 update! All my prior versions were developed using Android Studio v2.X.X. Not sure, but if that matters..

[image]

Comment: Update: It's fixed now!