# My android app keeps updating in playstore even I update the latest version

Tags: android, android-studio, updates, publishing

I couldn't find any similar topic in here or google. I uploaded an app in play store and then I uploaded a new version of it. But now, It always asks for an update in market. I don't know is it due to my code or something. When I upload an update I increase the versionCode and rename the versionName in android studio then sign it[image]

Then I go to play console - select the app - release management - release dashboard [image]

Then I release my new version. I select "Android App Bundles and APKs to deactivate". I don't click "retain" It seems like a stupid post but I don't know what the problem is. I did it before I've never faced such an issue. I do everything like described in here https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/en-us/articles/360001395033-Android-How-to-Update-an-App-in-the-Google-Play-Developer-Console

Finally it always asks for update in the market

[image]

I would be glad for any tiny idea. If stackoverflow is not the correct place for this post can you at least redirect me the correct place? Thanks.

Comment: it will show update option always when you upload apk with updated version, and we can upload apk with same or below  version code

Comment: Can we upload apk with same or below version code? It gives this error "You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code"

Comment: no, we can't go backward, android store will reject uploading same or below version code apk..

Comment: So, what do you mean by saying "and we can upload apk with same or below version code" in your first comment. Do you have any recommendation how to solve this problem?

Comment: oh sorry, I mistakenly write can instant of can't... please ignore first comment, i mean ,, we can'T upload apk with same or below version code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App on Google Play always shows "Update" instead of open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571956/app-on-google-play-always-shows-update-instead-of-open)