# Google Play Store showing Update button instead of Open button

Tags: android, publish

I have recently uploaded app on play store and installs the app successfully on device.However, in play store "UPDATE" button is activated instead of "OPEN" button.Ideally it should show "OPEN" button only

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Close once play store & reopen again or check the version of your app.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Already done & checked this but issue persist versionCode : 3 (greater than previous 2 )versionName : "1.2" (greater than previous 1.1 )

Comment: If the version code is different than in any case it will show update button.

Comment: @adnankhalil But it is fresh install on new device then it should not show

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and then install the app from play store again?

Comment: @SrinivasGuni have you tried?

Comment: once clear data of google play store  from app setting then open.. it will work

Comment: @adnankhalil yes brother did it already

Comment: @ChiragNahar did this also before no change

Comment: I have also added link of my app in my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App on Google Play always shows "Update" instead of open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571956/app-on-google-play-always-shows-update-instead-of-open)